# Have Divs Fill Width of Container

Tags: css

I have a container that is dynamically generated on the fly.  It will end up with either a single div inside it, or two divs inside it.

The first div may or may not be there, but the second div is always there.  I need that second div to always fill up the entire width.

It fills the width when the first div is there, but when it isn't there it doesn't go all the way.

Here is the current CSS I am using:

```
.div1 {
  display: table-cell;
}
.div2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

NOTE: Both of these divs have form fields and labels.

Comment: Do you have a demo of the problem?

Comment: To extend what @BurningLights was saying, if you post a JSFiddle of your specific problem, it will help a lot. The specific formatting of the parent div above `.div1` and `.div2` might be what's causing it to not act as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add a parent element that has `display:table` style:

```css
.table{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

.div1 {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>div1 has content</h2>
<div class="table">
    <div class="div1">some content</div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>

<br/>

<h2>div1 has no content</h2>
<div class="table">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>

<br/>

<h2>no div1</h2>
<div class="table">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b78ym3jf/)